# Selection of Numbers such that no selection has more than 1 term same

Tags: combinatorics

What are the number of ways of selecting 8 numbers from 1 to N such that not more than 1 number is same in any selection? (for N >= 100)
Edit:-
Let n be the total number of sets, if U1,...,Un be the sets, then for any i, n(Ui intersection Uj) <= 1 for all j != i

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to know how many sets of 8 numbers you can make from $N$ numbers without repetition of numbers from the previous sets. You can have up to $\lfloor N/8 \rfloor$ sets.

Comment: Let n be the total number of sets, if U1,...,Un be the sets, then for any i, n(Ui intersection Uj) <= 1 for all j != i

Comment: Your comment is a better way to phrase it.  Please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how many options you have to choose from for each of the 8 numbers. E.g. for the first number you pick you have N options, but then for the 2nd number you are more restricted because you can't pick the same number again. Once you know how many choices you have for each of the 8 numbers you  need to multiply these together (use multiplication here because we're counting the branches of a tree: we start with N branches for choosing the first number, then each one splits into M different branches for the second number, giving a total of $N\times M$ different branches, and so on). Finally, if you don't care about the order of your list of numbers, you need to divide by the number of ways to re-arrange (permute) the list (since our process has counted the number of *ordered* lists). That's just $8! = 8\times 7\times \dots \times 2 \times 1$.

Comment: Is there an Algorithm to construct the sequences if I want to using a programming language?

Comment: This does not answer the question, which OP has clarified in a comment.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to clear what I meant

Comment: My bad, I thought you were just choosing one set of eight at a time. Are you trying to find $n$, or count the number of distinct ways to choose $U_1, \dots, U_n$?